# How to passing image captured from camera to C function via Jni?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-camera

I'm developing an Android app works with image captured from camera. I decided to use native C as the main processing.

I just learn about Jni few days ago and build some simple app with this, but I don't know how to passing image captured from camera to C function.

Please tell me how to do it or give a detail example is best.

Thanks.

Comment: show us what your tried, or be more specific

Comment: I just have an idea in my head. But now I need to pass image data from camera to C function and check weather it success